# Java method chaining with casting on a single line

Tags: java

I need to add two values together, and they are both stored as Longs in an object HashMap.
This is what I'm trying to do, and my IDE says that it is an error.

```
long total = currentRowContents.get("value_A").longValue() + currentRowContents.get("value_B").longValue();
```

I'm guessing this wont work because currentRowContents is a HashMap type *Object*, and so what is returned from *currentRowContents.get(...)* will need to be cast as type *Long*, then I can use the *.longValue()* method on it.

I know that I can solve the issue by splitting it all up into separate statements and doing some casting. But I was wondering if there was a way of getting the above to work without splitting it up, and if it does need casting (which I'm sure it does) where to put it?

**EDIT**
Not that it changes anything, but for those who'd like to know more, the answers that I have received do solve the problems. But the Hash Map I'm using is type *Object, Object*, though it is more used like *String, Object*, and it does contain data from a database. Unfortunately I can't change the Hash Map as it comes from a piece of purpose built framework that I cannot change.

Comment: please supply ALL informations, e.g. the error message of the IDE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look like you're using a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) for your `Map`. Given that `longValue()` is used in your question, it is reasonable to assume that the values of the `Map` are of type `Long`

Generics can be used to remove the need for casting

```
Map<String, Long> currentRowContents = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

If the source of the `Map` is not within your control then casting is necessary

```
long total = ((Long)currentRowContents.get("value_A")).longValue() + 
                  ((Long)currentRowContents.get("value_B")).longValue();
```

Comment: You are assuming that all values in the map are Longs. That is not necessarily true.

Comment: @MarounMaroun What if the `Map` comes from some other code which he doesn't have access ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Then he'll have to cast :)

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question. He is asking how to cast and call a method in a single line. This explains nothing about that.

Comment: @Pablo if not all entries are Long, than the code should check that. However, the documented code does show no case distinctions

Comment: If the user has control over the code, using generics should be the first approach to take. Failing that casting is the option to take

Comment: @Pablo I think you are not fair, I would like to downvote you, but this is not supported yet.

Comment: I have found methods that return Map<String, Object> too many times (for example in database access) to assume tha he is actually using raw types.

Comment: @Pablo, if so the given code is totally wrong, not the answer is reimeus

Comment: @stefanbachert Sorry? If there are APIs that return a Map<String, Object>, because they return mixed types in the map, how is the code wrong?

Comment: @Pablo try to get a longValue say from a instance of class Person. Either the declaration of Map is correct, than calculating total is wrong, or vice versa. In this sense the answer of Reimeus is totally adequate

Answer (score 4):

Can cast the `Object` to `Long` :

```
((Long)currentRowContents.get("value_A")).longValue();


long total = ((Long)currentRowContents.get("value_A")).longValue() + 
             ((Long)currentRowContents.get("value_B")).longValue();
```

*I'm guessing this wont work because currentRowContents is a HashMap type Object,*

If possible then use the correct type for the `Map` if all the values in `Map` are `Long` and you have access or authorization to the code which declares the `Map` :

```
Map<String, Long> currentRowContents;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the casts before calling the method, but it would be a better idea to specify the generic type of that `Map`.

```
long total = ((Long)currentRowContents.get("value_A")).longValue() 
  + ((Long)currentRowContents.get("value_B")).longValue();
```

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Working Subpar
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("value1", new Long(10));
    map.put("value2", new Long(10));

    long total = ((Long)map.get("value1")).longValue() +
        ((Long)map.get("value2")).longValue(); 
    System.out.println(total);

    //Optimal Approach
    Map<String,Long> map2 = new HashMap<String,Long>();
    map2.put("value1", new Long(10));
    map2.put("value2", new Long(10));

    Long total2 = map2.get("value1")+ map2.get("value2"); 
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

cast before calling a method:

```
((Long) obj).longValue();
```

I keep it abstract, because this can be done with any `Object`, you get the idea. Just make sure to use double parathesis when performing an inline cast. And of course make sure your `Object` really is a `Long` value to avoid `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 0):

Here i use object, first i convert it to the string and then parse it into long.

```
HashMap<String, Object> a= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    a.put("1", 700);
     a.put("2", 900);
     long l=Long.parseLong(a.get("1").toString())+Long.parseLong(a.get("2").toString());
    System.out.println(l);
```